# The product variation ID that was recently added to the shopping cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Solution 1:

```
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
$product_id = end($items)['variation_id'];
```

I have been told that Now may be my problem is that this is not refreshed when using ajax add to cart.

please make a little test in my test website: https://bestfh.com/product/pu-leather-multifunctional-car-seat-cover/

Step 1: add 4 colors in sort, black , gray , gray/black/ tan color to cart, it return message with picture shows correctly.

step 2: Then, same product, not matter what color you add to cart will still show **tan** color picture.

---

since very difficult to solve the problem this way. I try use different way to solve this:

Solution2:

in functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart',10,3 );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_data,$productId, $variation_id ) {

   setcookie("newtocart", $variation_id);
}
```

in success.php

```
$product_id = $_COOKIE["newtocart"];
```

The issue is: it seems like runs success.php first then functions.php,   it's always late for one time.

- Time 1:  I added the black color, $product_id shows empty.
- Time 2:  I added the gray color,  $product_id will shows black color's ID.
- Time 3:  I added the tan color,  $product_id will shows gray color's ID.

If this solution 1's problem is not refreshed when using ajax add to cart.  what should I do?

if you knows how to make solution 2 work correctly, please also let me know

Comment: the cookie won't be applied to the page until its refreshed. your site isn't loading for me so other than that I don't know what it might be.

Comment: Thanks, the website Is located in us.

Comment: Thanks for help, I use session to solve this problem.